# .htaccess won't let me enter a subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I have joomla in a hosting, and it is working fine.
But I want to create a small webservice for an app, so I created a subfolder in my root folder  to have access like this: www.mydomain.com/myfolder

The problem is, the .htaccess is automatically redirecting me to the joomla index. I don't have experience with the .htaccess configuration at all. I have been reading some tutorials, but every time I change something, the joomla stops working properly. 
Here is my htaccess file:

```
rewriterule ^component/users/(.*)$ index.php?option=com_comprofiler&task=login [L]
rewritecond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
rewritecond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
rewritecond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
rewritecond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
rewriterule .* index.php [F]
rewriterule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
rewriterule .* index.php [L]
```

Creating a subdomain is not an option (I only have access to the ftp)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right after `rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php`, add:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myfolder/
```

That should exclude any request for `/myfolder/` from getting routed to joomla's `index.php` file.